# Python MIT Course OCW Web Page SCraper

Tags: python, scraper

So I got this MIT Scraper program to get it working. Somebody worked on it before and has been told that it's functioning and the coding is correct. I just have to fix some config issue and should be written.

First of all here is the link to the full program: https://github.com/ByteAcademyCo/mit_scraper
{take a look at the ocw_upload and those main three files 
config.py, mit_ocw_scraper.py and read_imsmanifest.py

If you can take a look at it and explain what everything does that would more than amazing, cause I don't count myself as an expert at python yet.

To generate schemas for courses...
Download and unzip a course's content from the ocw site and add its path to COURSE_FOLDERS
in the config file located in the ocw_upload folder. By running read_imsmanifest.py, every imsmanifest file 
included in the course's content folder will be parsed 
and important information, including the sections into which the course is organized,
paths to the course's resources (but not the actual data for those resources), and other specifications 
of the course, will be written to a json file as specified in build_schema.py. 
The exact schema used to organize each course's content can be 
found in schema_dict.py

I have done all those stuff and got a little idea on how things work so in my opinion, I feel that 
**something is either wrong with this part of the code**

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
import xmltodict
import os

import config
from build_schema import SchemaBuilder

class Director:

```
def __init__(self, builder, config, course_folder):
    self.full_path = os.path.join(config.COURSES_DIR, course_folder)
    self.file_full_path = os.path.join(self.full_path, config.IMS_MANIFEST)

    self._builder = builder
    self.imsmanifest_reader = IMSManifestReader(self._builder, self.file_full_path)


def construct(self):
    """
    Instruct reader to process input and pass specified data 
    to the builder for the product to be constructed.
    """
    self.imsmanifest_reader.process()
```

class IMSManifestReader:

```
XMLNAMESPACES = {
        "default": "http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1",
        "xsi" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "adlcp" : "http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2",
        "cwsp" : "http://www.dspace.org/xmlns/cwspace_imscp",
        "ocw" : "https://ocw.mit.edu/xmlns/ocw_imscp",
        "lom" : "https://ocw.mit.edu/xmlns/LOM"
    }

def __init__(self, builder, imsmanifest):
    self._builder = builder
    self.imsmanifest = imsmanifest


def process(self):
    """
    Parse input, pass data to builder for construction of product.
    """
    root = self.find_imsmanifest_root(self.imsmanifest)
    item_parent_map = self.map_parents_items(self.imsmanifest)

    organizations = self.read_organizations(root, item_parent_map)
    resources = self.read_resources(root)
    metadata = self.read_subject_metadata(root)
    course_name = self.read_course_name(root)
    course_code = self.read_course_code(root)
    course_version = self.read_version(root)
    course_instructor = self.read_instructor(root)

    product = self._builder.get_product()



def find_imsmanifest_root(self, imsmanifest):
    """
    Read imsmanifest.xml into an element tree, find root.

    Args: imsmanifest - full path for imsmanifest file

    Returns: Root element of imsmanifest document's tree

    """

    print(imsmanifest)
    tree = ElementTree.parse(imsmanifest)
    root = tree.getroot()
    root_attribs = root.attrib
    return root

def map_parents_items(self, imsmanifest):
    """
    Map items to organization parent elements from 
    imsmanifest document tree.

    Args: imsmanifest - full path for imsmanifest file

    Returns: Dictionary with item ids as keys 
            and parent ids as values
    """

    tree = ElementTree.parse(imsmanifest)
    item_parent_map = {}
    for parent in tree.iter():
        for child in parent:
            if "item" in child.tag:
                item_parent_map[child.attrib["identifier"]] = parent.attrib["identifier"]

    return item_parent_map


def read_organizations(self, root, item_parent_map):
    """
    Get identifier, title, items of each organization
    and pass these attributes to organization builder.

    Args:   
        root - root of entire imsmanifest's document tree 
               which is an instance of the ElementTree wrapper class 
        item_parent_map - dictionary with item ids as keys
                             and their parents' ids as values 

    """

    organizations_element = root.find("default:organizations", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    organization_elements = organizations_element.findall("default:organization", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    for organization in organization_elements:
        org_id = organization.attrib["identifier"]
        title = organization.find("default:title", self.XMLNAMESPACES).text
        self._builder.add_organization(org_id, title)
        self.read_items(org_id, organization, item_parent_map)

def read_items(self, org_id, parent_node, item_parent_map):
    """
    Get identifier, title, parent item identifier,
    and other attributes of each item, pass these
    features to item builder

    Args: org_id - parent organization id
          parent_node - parent of item (organization or item)
          item_parent_map - dictionary with item ids as keys and their parents' 
                            ids as values

    """
    item_elements = parent_node.findall("default:item", self.XMLNAMESPACES)

    for item in item_elements:
        item_identifier = item.attrib["identifier"]

        item_info = {}
        for key, value in item.attrib.items():
            if key != "identifier":
                item_info[key] = value

        item_info["title"] = item.find("default:title", self.XMLNAMESPACES).text
        item_info["parent identifier"] = item_parent_map[str(item.attrib["identifier"])]

        self._builder.add_item(item_identifier, item_info, org_id)

        # #check for subitems
        if item.attrib["identifier"] in item_parent_map.values():
            self.read_items(org_id, item, item_parent_map)



def read_resources(self, root):
    """
    Get identifier, type, href, dependencies,
    metadata, files of each resource
    and pass these attributes to resource builder.

    Args:   
        root - root of entire imsmanifest's document tree 
               which is an instance of the ElementTree wrapper class 
    """

    resources_element = root.find("default:resources", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    resource_elements = resources_element.findall("default:resource", self.XMLNAMESPACES)

    for resource in resource_elements:
        resource_id = resource.attrib["identifier"]

        #type, href are attributes of each resource element
        resource_info = {}
        for key, value in resource.attrib.items():
            if key != "identifier":
                resource_info[key] = value

        self._builder.add_resource(resource_id, resource_info)

    #   #check for dependencies
        dependency = resource.find("default:dependency", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
        if dependency != None:
            self.read_dependencies(resource_id, resource)

    #   #check for files
        file = resource.find("default:file", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
        if file != None:
            self.read_files(resource_id, resource)

    #   #check for metadata
        metadata = resource.find("default:metadata", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
        if metadata != None:
            self.read_document_metadata(resource_id, resource)



def read_dependencies(self, resource_identifier, resource_node):
    """
    Get all identifier references of dependencies for a given resource,
    pass resource_identifier and list of dependency identifierrefs to
    builder

    Args: 
        resource_identifier - identifier of parent resource
        resource_node - resource object element to be searched for 
                        dependency subelements
    """
    dependencies = []
    dependency_elements = resource_node.findall("default:dependency", self.XMLNAMESPACES)

    for dependency in dependency_elements:
        identifier_ref = dependency.attrib["identifierref"]
        dependencies.append(identifier_ref)

    self._builder.add_dependencies(resource_identifier, dependencies)


def read_files(self, resource_identifier, resource_node):
    """
    Get all hrefs of files for a given resource,
    pass resource_identifier and list of file hrefs to builder

    Args: 
        resource_identifier - identifier of parent resource
        resource_node - resource object element to be searched for 
                        dependency subelements
    """
    files = []

    file_elements = resource_node.findall("default:file", self.XMLNAMESPACES)

    for file in file_elements:
        href = file.attrib["href"]
        files.append(href)

    self._builder.add_files(resource_identifier, files)


def read_document_metadata(self, resource_identifier, resource):
    """
    Get metadata for a specified resource and pass to doc metadata builder

    Args: 
        resource_identifier - identifier of parent resource
        resource_node - resource object element to be searched for 
                        dependency subelements
    """
    metadata_element = resource.find("default:metadata", self.XMLNAMESPACES)

    metadata = {}
    namespace = self.XMLNAMESPACES["adlcp"] + "/location"
    metadata = metadata_element.find("adlcp:location", self.XMLNAMESPACES).text

    self._builder.add_doc_metadata(resource_identifier, namespace, metadata)


def read_subject_metadata(self, root):
    """
    Get subject level metadata element object
     and pass to subject metadata builder. 

    Args: root - root of entire imsmanifest's document tree 
                 which is an instance of the ElementTree wrapper class 
    """
    metadata_element = root.find("default:metadata", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    stringified_metadata = ElementTree.tostring(metadata_element, encoding="unicode")
    metadata_dict = xmltodict.parse(stringified_metadata, process_namespaces=True)

    self._builder.add_subject_metadata(metadata_dict)

def read_course_name(self, root):
    """
    Get the course name from metadata and pass it to metadata schema builder

    Args: root - root of entire imsmanifest's document tree 
                 which is an instance of the ElementTree wrapper class 
    """

    metadata_element = root.find("default:metadata", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    general_info_element = metadata_element.find("lom:general", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    title_element = general_info_element.find("lom:title", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    course_name = title_element.find("lom:string", self.XMLNAMESPACES).text

    self._builder.add_schema_metadata("name", course_name)

def read_course_code(self, root):
    """
    Get the course code from metadata and pass it to metadata schema builder

    Args: root - root of entire imsmanifest's document tree 
                 which is an instance of the ElementTree wrapper class 
    """
    metadata_element = root.find("default:metadata", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    general_info_element = metadata_element.find("lom:general", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    identifier_element = general_info_element.find("lom:identifier", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    course_code = identifier_element.find("lom:entry", self.XMLNAMESPACES).text

    self._builder.add_schema_metadata("courseCode", course_code)

def read_version(self, root):
    """
    Get the version of the course from metadata 
    and pass it to metadata schema builder

    Args: root - root of entire imsmanifest's document tree 
                 which is an instance of the ElementTree wrapper class 
    """
    metadata_element = root.find("default:metadata", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    lifecycle_element = metadata_element.find("lom:lifecycle", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    version_element = lifecycle_element.find("lom:version", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    course_version = version_element.find("lom:string", self.XMLNAMESPACES).text

    self._builder.add_schema_metadata("version", course_version)

def read_instructor(self, root):
    """
    Get the instructor of the course from metadata 
    and pass it to metadata schema builder

    Args: root - root of entire imsmanifest's document tree 
                 which is an instance of the ElementTree wrapper class 
    """
    metadata_element = root.find("default:metadata", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    lifecycle_element = metadata_element.find("lom:lifecycle", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    contribute_element = lifecycle_element.find("lom:contribute", self.XMLNAMESPACES)
    try:
        author = contribute_element.find("lom:entity", self.XMLNAMESPACES).text
    except:
        author = ''

    self._builder.add_schema_metadata("Instructor", author)
```

def main():
    for course_folder in range(0, 2389):
        course_folder = str(course_folder)
        director = Director(SchemaBuilder(course_folder), config, course_folder)
        director.construct()

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()

**or the config.py**

COURSES_DIR = "../courses"

COURSE_FOLDERS = [
    'C:/Users/ycberrehouma/Desktop/18-06-spring-2010'

]

IMS_MANIFEST = "imsmanifest.xml"

**build_schema.py**

import schema_dict 
import json
from file_schema import addDirToIPFS

class SchemaBuilder():
    """
    Construct and assemble parts of the product by implementing the
    Builder interface.
    Define and keep track of the representation it creates.
    Provide an interface for retrieving the product.

```
"""
def __init__(self, dir):
    self._product = Product(dir)


def add_organization(self, org_identifier, org_title):

    """
    Add to dictionary of organizations with the organization's
    identifier as the key and a dictionary as the value 
    (with 'title' and 'items' as keys of this dictionary)

    Args:
        org_identifier - identifier of organization provided by imsmanifest
        org_title - title of organization specified in imsmanifest
    """
    info = {
        "title" : org_title,
        "items" : {}
    }

    self._product.organizations[org_identifier] = info

def add_item(self, item_identifier, item_info, org_id):

    """
    Add item and its associated info to 'items' within
    its parent organization in the dictionary of 
    organizations.

    Args:
        item_identifier - identifier of item provided by imsmanifest
        item_info - other info (the item's title, parent identifier, 
                    other attributes such as an identifierref, 
                    a sectionTemplateTag, etc.) 
        org_id - parent organization of item
    """

    item_dict = {}
    item_dict[item_identifier] = item_info
    self._product.organizations[org_id]['items'].update(item_dict)

def add_resource(self, resource_identifier, resource_info):
    """
    Add a resource to dictionary of resources 
    with the resource's identifier as the key
    and any other attributes as values.

    Args:
        resource_identifier - identifier of resource provided by imsmanifest
        resource_info - dict of other info (including the resource's type, hrefs)
                        with the name of attributes as keys 
                        and associated info as values

    """
    self._product.resources[resource_identifier] = resource_info

def add_dependencies(self, resource_identifier, dependencies):
    """
    Add key-value pair of dependencies of specified resource 
    to resource dictionary.

    Args:
        resource_identifier : identifier of resource provided by imsmanifest
        dependencies: list of identifierrefs for dependencies of specified resource
    """
    self._product.resources[resource_identifier]["dependencies"] = dependencies

def add_files(self, resource_identifier, files):
    """
    Add key-value pair of files for specified resource 
    to resource dictionary ("files" as key and list of
    hrefs of files as the value)

    Args:
        resource_identifier : identifier of resource provided by imsmanifest
        files: list of hrefs for files of specified resource
    """
    self._product.resources[resource_identifier]["files"] = files

def add_doc_metadata(self, resource_identifier, namespace, metadata):
    """
    Add key-value pair of metadata for specified resource
    to resource dictionary ("metadata" as key 
    and {namespace: metadata text} as value)

    Args: 
        resource_identifier : identifier of resource provided by imsmanifest
        namespace: full namespace of metadata (adlcp + location)
        metadata: text of metadata element
    """
    metadata_dict = {
            namespace : metadata
        }

    self._product.resources[resource_identifier]["metadata"] = metadata_dict

def add_subject_metadata(self, metadata):
    """
    Assign subject level metadata element (its subelements 
    and attributes) to an ordered dictionary of metadata.

    Args: metadata - ordered dictionary generated from
                     metadata element object 
                     (information includes metadata elements tag, 
                      subelement tags, attributes, text)
    """
    self._product.metadata = metadata

def add_schema_metadata(self, key, data):
    """
    Add key-value pair of metadata to dictionary of schema data.

    Args:
        key - Corresponds to key in schema with same name
        data - metadata bound to type
    """
    self._product.schema_data[key] = data

def get_product(self):
    self._product.to_schema()
    self._product.schema_to_file()
```

class Product:
    def **init**(self, dir):
        self.organizations = {}
        self.resources = {}
        self.metadata = {}
        self.schema_data = {}
        self.schema = schema_dict.schema
        self.dir = dir

```
def to_schema(self):
    #pass resources, organizations, metadata into schema
    self.schema["resources"] = self.resources
    self.schema["organizedMaterial"] = self.organizations
    self.schema["courseSpecifications"] = self.metadata

    #pass specific metadata (metadata common to every course) into schema
    self.course_name_to_schema()
    self.course_code_to_schema()
    self.version_to_schema()
    self.instructor_to_schema()

def course_name_to_schema(self):
    course_name = self.schema_data["name"]
    self.schema["name"] = course_name

def course_code_to_schema(self):
    course_code = self.schema_data["courseCode"]
    self.schema["courseCode"] = course_code

def version_to_schema(self):
    version = self.schema_data["version"]
    self.schema["version"] = version

def instructor_to_schema(self):
    instructor = self.schema_data["Instructor"]
    self.schema["hasCourseInstance"]["Instructor"]["name"] = instructor

    self.schema["IPFS_files"] = addDirToIPFS(self.dir)


def schema_to_file(self):
    with open('../courses/'+self.dir+'/schema.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(self.schema, outfile)
```

**When I run the read_imsmanifest.xml I get those errors**
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfieM.png

Thank you so much for your intention and let me know if you need more details

Comment: No. Instead please post a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So i have reedited the question thanks to @mhawke Any thoughts. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

The error message in the traceback clearly identifies the problem: the file `imsmanifest.xml` can not be found. Either the path is incorrect, file/directory permissions do not allow access, or because the path is a relative path and you are running the program from the wrong directory.

First thing to do is check that the path `./courses\\0\\imsmanifest.xml` is valid from the directory in which you execute the program. I noticed that your code defines the courses directory to be `../courses`, not `./courses` as shown in the traceback, so you also need to check that.

You can test using an interactive Python session. Run a command shell, change to the directory in which you normally run the program, start Python, then type `open('./courses\\0\\imsmanifest.xml')`. If that doesn't work, try: `open(r'.\courses\0\ismanifest.xml')`.

Possibly the mixed use of forward slashes and backslashes in the path might be the problem. I can't verify this, but I believe that it shouldn't matter. You could eliminate that as being the problem by ensuring that backslashes are used in `config.py`, i.e. try `COURSES_DIR = r"..\courses"`